# Can't reference javascript functions from a module

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html page, which references a javascript module:

```
<head>
    <script type="module" src="mymodule.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="doStuff()">
    . . .
```

The javascript file looks like this:

```
export function doStuff() {
    console.log('test');
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

```
columns.html:8 Uncaught TypeError: doStuff is not a function
    at onload (myPage.html:8)
```

If I change the HTML to:

```
<script src="mymodule.js"></script>
```

Then it works; however, this then doesn't let me reference a second javascript library from mymodule.js.  My question is, why can it not find the function when it's referenced as a module?

Comment: shouldn't the  `<script type="module" src="mymodule.js"></script>` be at the bottom of the html script opposed to being on the head ? maybe im wrong idk.

Comment: Why not using `DOMContentLoaded` event

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter where I put the `<script type="module" src="mymodule.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  import { doStuff } from 'mymodule.js';
</script>
<body onload="doStuff()">
....
</body>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make any difference